# Allow user to choose default store/language in Magento CE 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, localization

We want to allow the user to choose a 'default' or 'preferred' store (or language) and set this in their account.

So that when a French user logs into the site, the French store is served as their default, for example.

I've looked for this functionality for ages, is it built-in? If so, how do I use/activate it? Any helpful comments are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing from out-of-the-box Magento package.

Right now, a cookie is saved on customer browser to remember his selected language (store view) choice. If that's not enough for you, you could create an additional customer attribute to store that selection and then read that value on customer log-in.